# South needs DROP privileges, that seems unsafe, is there a way of working to avoid this

Tags: django, django-south

I introduced South in a project. I got into trouble, because of the fact that South needs DROP privileges. The error I got:

(1142, "DROP command denied to user '?????' for table 'ROLLBACK_TEST'")

After that, the migration seemed borked. I had to drop my database and re-create it.

When running the South command, the 'default' Django connection is used. So, the associated user (that is also used for the front-end website) needs to have DROP privileges. To me, this seems a bit dangerous. Is there a way around this potentially unsafe approach?

Answer (score 2):

1) Copy your `settings.py` to a new file `south_settings.py`, and remove everything except the DATABASES key.

2) Prepend `from settings import *` to import the existing `settings.py` keys.

3) Edit the `USER` and `PASSWORD` values to reflect a newly created SQL user with DROP privileges.

```
# south_settings.py
from settings import *

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',  # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'django_db',  # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'username_with_drop_privileges',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'password_with_drop_privileges',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

You merely override the DATABASES key value in this new `south_settings.py`.

---

4) Finally, execute `python manage.py [command]` using the `--settings=south_settings` argument.

```
python manage.py migrate [app] --settings=south_settings
```

Comment: Tx, that is a nice approach. Since I use buildout icm. with djangorecipe I think it would even be possible to generate a separate script for this.